# show div when mouse over

Tags: css, html, hover, block

How can I make a link that appears when the mouse is over the main area like a youtube comment.

I have this code - but when the mouse is over the .showme class it's not visible like the showhim element.

```
<div class="showhim">HOVER ME<div class="showme">hai</div></div>

.showme{ 
display: none;
}
.showhim:hover .showme{
display : block;
}
```

Comment: Works for me: See this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AaronBlenkush/Y8Ygh/

Comment: I need it also to be visible when over showme. Look at youtube when your mouse is over the little cross (Report)

Comment: It *is* also visible when hovering over `.showme`, since `.showme` is a child of `.showhim`... Did you try the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AaronBlenkush/Y8Ygh/1/)? What browser & version are you running this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want the inner div to be in the flow of the outer. In that case use

```
.showhim:hover .showme{
    display : inline-block;
}
```

Or, if you want to display the inner div on `:hover` for the inner div too, use

```
showme{ 
    visibility: hidden;
}
.showhim:hover .showme{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Just one thing: Maybe you tested with IE 6. The dirty one from Redmond doesn't know `:hover` on elements other than `<a/>`. He doesn't know `display: inline-block` either by the way.

Comment: @AaronBlenkush, +1 so let's hope you have like 7 billion friends. ;-)

Comment: It looks like the same. Please take a look at my comment above.

Comment: "You want to use `visibility` when you want the element to hold its space even when it’s not seen. You want to use `display` when you want the element to give back its space allowing the other elements on your page to collapse around it." (http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/visibility-vs-display/)